# qgis Points data from KML file

Tags: qgis, kml, import

I have a KML file with Waypoints and several Tracks in it. When I open the file with QGIS, I see the LineString for each Track as well as a Points array for each Track. My problem is: QGIS shows the same Points array for each Track, even though there are discrete Points arrays for each Track in the KML file.

My process for opening the file was to start QGIS, click on "Add Vector Layer" and choosing "Select All" in the dialog that appeared listing each Folder in the KML file. I have also tried opening the file and importing only a single Points array instead of everything; I still get only the first Points array specified for the first Track in the KML file instead of the Points array for a specific Track.

Comment: So to clarify, are you seeing multiple copies of the same linestring? Or are you seeing multiple linestrings but only one set of points? In GPS, waypoints are typically independent of tracks - they're just point markers. If I understand the process/format of your data, the points that make up the linestrings (or tracks) are just the coordinate pairs of each vertex of the linestring - they wouldn't be read in as points, you'd need to extract them to points from the linestrings if you wanted them as such.

Comment: Multiple linestrings are present (one for each track), only one set of points (even though multiple sets of points exist in the KML file.) The KML file has the waypoint information stored in a separate folder. For each track in the KML file, the structure is: track folder which has two separate sub-folders, one for the Points array (which contain marker names and descriptions to go along with the coordinates), and one for the LineString data (which is just an array of coordinates and altitudes). My goal is to extract the Points array (from which I could interpolate the linestring).